# Basic react component not rendering

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot

i'm using spring boot and my index.html is in src/main/resources/templates directory and below is the content. If i render a static content from html itself it renders but when i try to render from react component it doesn't render anything

```
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <title>ReactJS + Spring Data REST</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.5.4/react.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.5.4/react-dom.min.js"></script>
      <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.23/browser.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="react"></div>
    <script src="built/bundle.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

my react component is in src/main/js/ directory and app.js file
Below is the all the codes i have in the app.js file

```
import React from 'react';
import {render} from 'react-dom';
import RendorTest from 'components/RendorTest';
class RendorTest extends React.component{
    rendor(){
        return(
            <div><h1>Spring Boot + Rest + React.js</h1></div>
        );
    }
}
var element = <RendorTest />;
ReactDOM.render(
        element,document.getElementById('react')
    )
```

Comment: rendor() is that typo mistake?

Comment: Change `rendor` to `render`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why you're importing RendorTest and then declaring another class of the same name, but you are also extending the wrong method on the React object. You need to `extend React.Component { }` not `.component`.

You could also `import React, { Component } from "react";` and then `extend Component { }`

As ahutch mentioned, you also need to call the `render()` method, rendor() is not a method of `React.Component`.

Answer (score 0):

Kyle is right and also you want to call `render()` and not `rendor()`. This component is also probably better written as a stateless functional component, for example:

```
const RendorTest = (props) => { 
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Spring Boot + Rest + React.js</h1>
      </div>
     )
}
```